# searching a keyword in DAX

Tags: search, powerbi, contains, keyword, dax

I am trying to create a column in power BI that searches for a keyword in a column of a table and returns a category.

For example: in table 1 there is a column with feedback and if it contains any keyword in the keyword column of table 2 ( which is updated regularly) a TRUE value is returned.

The following code works great if the keyword is the only word in the sentence like "product broke after using it once" returns FALSE if looking for the keyword "broke" and the word "broke" used as the only word in the sentence returns TRUE

```
Column = if(
CONTAINS(Products,Products[feedback],RELATED(feedbackList[keywords]))
,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

So basically it only returns if the value is matched exactly and not as part of a sentence.

I hope someone can help,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are creating the calculated column in TableA, you already have a filter context in TableA so you only need to iterate over TableB in order to get the description you need.

Let me know if the following works:

```
ColumnMeasure =

calculate(

if(

countrows(values('Table B'[Colmn B2]))>1,

"More than 1 classification found",

values('Table B'[Colmn B2])

),

filter(

all('Table B'[Colmm B1]),

search('Table B'[Colmn B1],'Table A'[Colmn A1],1,0)<>0

  )

)
```

There are more similar examples here:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2011/12/30/string-comparison-in-dax.aspx

Comment: I tried the solution above and it does work great but for some reason on power BI some keywords are matched and others ignored even with the spelling correct. But thank you for your help, they may be some other problem with the data I am working with

Comment: It actually worked even better when I used different data, thanks again for your help Ameya